# Change font to “Times New Roman” in math mode (e.g., $ equation $) in PDFLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, fonts, pdftex

I would like to have a unique font (Times New Roman or an equivalent one) for both text and equations.

I'm actually using the commands below, which work only for text mode:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
```

example:[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,b5paper,12pt,fleqn]{psd_thesis}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}           
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}                

% Document
\begin{document}
example text mode: 12345

$example \ math \ mode: 12345$
\end{document}
```

The psd_thesis.cls is reported below:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{psd_thesis}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}

\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass{report}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  % Double-spaced

\usepackage[round]{natbib}  % bib style

\usepackage[tx]{sfmath}      % a package of fonts
\usepackage{helvet}             % For Helvetica (Arial is just a bad copy of Helvetica)
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}  

\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{50\p@}%  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \large \scshape \bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
\fi
\interlinepenalty\@M
\large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@  }}

\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{50\p@}%{\parindent \z@ \raggedright
\normalfont
\interlinepenalty\@M
\large \scshape \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
\vskip 40\p@  }}  

\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}% % the name{1}% % the level{0mm}% % the indent{3.0\baselineskip}% % the before skip{2.5\baselineskip}% % the after skip{\normalfont \normalsize}} % the style

\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}% % the name
{2}% % the level{0mm}% % the indent{-\baselineskip}% % the before skip{1.5\baselineskip}% % the after skip{\normalfont \normalsize}} % the style

\endinput
```

Comment: You *do* get Times for math letters, unless you follow that`\usepackage` call with some other font selection. A minimal example is needed.

Comment: Now it's clearer: the fault is apparently on `psd_thesis.cls`, but a pointer to it is needed.

Comment: Remove `\usepackage[tx]{sfmath}` or, possibly, don't use the class at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the class is meant to typeset everything in a sans serif font. So, if you have to use it, don't try changing its settings.

If you are not required to use the class, just avoid it: its typographic decisions are funny, for example the enormous distance between a section title and the following text (twice and a half the baselineskip, with double spacing, means 1.85cm below; it's 2.2cm above).

Anyway, the part of the class that sets everything to sans serif is

```
\usepackage[tx]{sfmath}      % a package of fonts
\usepackage{helvet}             % For Helvetica (Arial is just a bad copy of Helvetica)
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

Comment it and you'll be free to choose whatever font you like.

Comment: I followed your suggestion but in math mode I got cursive Times New Roman for letters and a different style for numbers: 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jAwY0.jpg

I would like that numbers appear in the same style as the letters.
Thank you

Comment: @Luca I don't understand: it is traditional to have letters in math mode printed in italic shape and numbers upright.